# What intent should be used to open the Call accounts screen in Android?

Tags: android

I am building an app with VoIP, using a system managed ConnectionService. When registering the PhoneAccount, the user needs to manually enable the PhoneAccount somewhere in the Android system settings (or Dialer app settings?). If not enabled, the TelecomManager will not route VoIP calls.

How can I send the user to this "Call accounts" settings screen using an intent? I do not want the user to have to find this setting on his own.

Answer (score 3):

After some searching, I found this in a Google Group:

```
if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("Samsung")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.server.telecom",
        "com.android.server.telecom.settings.EnableAccountPreferenceActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    startActivity(new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_PHONE_ACCOUNTS));
}
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-contrib/C7qbnnAGzsk

Comment: No need to check if device is Samsung, it works also xiomi and huawei devices

Comment: Is there any way to skip this manual step? My app was working fine even with self_managed phone account and still showing the system's default calling screen but recently after certain Android updates, it started to show the `All Calling Accounts` screen when there is an incoming call.

Comment: Did you find any good solution @vikas?